# Dockerize android emulators inside VM

Tags: android, docker, testing, automation, android-emulator

I'm trying to build a automation testing solution and I bumped into a problem. I want to run android emulators (x86 not ARM) in containers but I'm already in a VM. Is there any solution aside from running them on the same host as VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution you need to enable nested virtualization:
https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android